# Debugging GO on VSCode using Delve

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, delve

I want to debug GoLang on VSCode editor. In their documentation they say it is possible. I am following the following Link to install the debugging features on the IDE.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go

And to install Delve they ask to follow these instructions
https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/windows/install.md

Once installation is completed they ask to run the following code

> $ mingw32-make install

But there is an error

> mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Does anybody know whats wrong with this? Has anything changed other than these instructions?

Comment: What directory are you in? I imagine there should be a Makefile in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this resolved. You don't want to install mingw for this. Instead run this code and make sure the dlv.exe which is created in any directory which is in your PATH variable in your computer.

```
$go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

I also did an writeup about debugging Golang using VSCode and Delve. If you are interested you can read it [here](http://www.tistuslabs.com/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-to-debug-golang-with-delve/).

Answer (score 1):

Run **mingw32-make install** command from directory created by **git clone https://github.com/derekparker/delve** command.